# How to call DblClick sub from code VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`. 
`Form1` has TextBox1 with double-click events:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  ' Some activity...
End Sub
```

`Form2` has `CommandButton2` with a click event:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  ' Another activity...
End Sub
```

I need to call the `TextBox1_DblClick` sub from the `CommandButton2_Click` sub.

How can I make a call like this?

Comment: Create a third `Sub` named anything (e.g. `MyActivity`) and have both `Click` routines call that sub. Then you can call it from anywhere, anytime.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought in this way but I wanted to find it could be straightforward solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a new **module**, add to it the sub with the operations you wish to perform

```
Sub mySubroutine()
    ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

Then call this from both of your click handlers

```
' In Form1
Public Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  mySubroutine
End Sub

' In Form2
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  mySubroutine
End Sub
```

If you wanted to pass stuff (like text box strings etc) from your forms, then include input arguments in your sub

```
Sub mySubroutine(str As String, n As Long) ' Passing arguments
    ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

Then pass those arguments when you make the call from anywhere

```
' Get a String and Long from data on the form, then call mySubroutine
mySubroutine str:=myString, n:=myLong
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used the solution like this.